# MEAN.js not showing in iframe

Tags: node.js, angularjs, meanjs

I have to display a MEAN.JS app within an iframe, so I started with a simple html file:

```
<iframe style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" src="http://localhost:3000/#!/workouts"></iframe>
```

But then the iframe content is empty, can please somebody help me?

Comment: Just for the sake of starting at the beginning, does the URL without the iframe 'http://localhost:3000/#!/workouts' display in the browser?

Comment: Yes it works perfectly fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it: My app is using Helmet (https://github.com/evilpacket/helmet) which setted a DENY in the X-Frame-Options. So, in my Express configuration I setted:

`app.use(helmet.xframe('ALLOW-FROM', 'www.mydomain.com'));`

And it worked